# How to use glassPane to create transparent window?

Tags: java, swing, transparency

Okay, so I want to make a Java JFrame that is transparent, but than has a the glassPane not transparent so I can make my own style of windows. can this be done?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Do you just want to create a window with no decoration (the title bar and borders) ?

Comment: I want to make a custom shaped window that shows the desktop bg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps with [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/).

Comment: AWTUtillities is depreciated. X_X

Comment: It's not deprecated; it's simply not supported.

Comment: Is Swing supported ?... Ok, ok, it's a funny joke.

Comment: @William its become a part of Java 7, but for Java 6 you will need to invoke it through the reflect API.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detail description of [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).

The marked answer has a wrong link.